# Headphones don't "isolate" speakers

Tags: audio, alsa, pulse-audio

I have bought some new 2.1 speakers but I have an issue. When I plug in the headphones the sound continues to play from the speakers (in a lower volume though). I re-ran alsaconf but I couldn't solve the problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @amphetamachine Please don't advise new users to repost; this leads to duplicate questions. Generally moderators handle such cases by migrating the question. (I've flagged, so a moderator will come along in a minute.)

Comment: How did you plug the headphones in? Into the speakers (some have a plug on the front to plug into)? Into the computer in a different port? A picture would be mildly helpful. Also, what make/model of speakers?

Comment: Hi, I plug them into the speakers port. The make/model is Turbox, made from local retailer. Also, why have you migrated the topic, the point is that the problem appears in Linux.